# Finding the effective switched capacitance of a processor

Tags: cpu, intel, frequency, energy

I need to determine the power consumption of a processor using the equation,

> P = C*(V^2)*f

where C is the effective switched capacitance, V is the supply voltage and f is the processor frequency. Could someone please explain me where I could find sample C and V values for a typical processor?. I have gone through some of the Intel processor data sheets, but haven't been able to figure out the typical C values of a processor.

The following link has a generic explanation of the CPU power consumption. However, in order to perform this power calculation, I need to know CL values as specified in this [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33318/power-consumed-by-a-cpu).

Could someone please provide me some tips or useful links where I could get the values for an Intel processor?.

Comment: Cross posting on Stack Exchange is strongly discouraged. (This question was also posted on [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213597/finding-the-effective-switched-capacitance-in-intel-processors).)

Comment: The CPU supply voltages are available on the fly from the motherboard's monitoring chips.  On Linux, install `lmsensors`.  On Windows, install the mobo manufacturer's software, or another tool like CPU-Z.  IIRC, the instantaneous power is also available.  Intel CPUs spend transistors on making this available to software so "average developers" can tune software to minimize power consumption.  I think `powertop` in Linux might show numbers.  Note that some CPUs (Haswell & Broadwell) have Fully-Integrated Voltage Regulators, so the voltage supplied by the mobo supplies multiple internal rails.

Comment: Someone posted a question on gate capacitance in one of my articles. Doing a quick search, I found [quite a bit of information](http://www.bing.com/search?q=gate+capacitance&qs=AS&pq=gate-capac&sc=6-10&sp=1&cvid=0C3C6A0B986A4C1DB70D21D85232002E&FORM=QBRE) ranging from simple transistors to VLSI.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you can't use that power equation in any useful way to measure the power of a modern Intel processor. The voltage requirements should be constant due to modern design needs. You can pull the actual power requirements from the design specs -- again, the designers of the motherboard and power supplies need to know this. This implies that the capacitance of the processor varies moment by moment. Though this is possible, it also may mean that this model of the internals of the processor is wrong.

I'm not saying that the venerated P=C*V^2*f is wrong but that it probably doesn't apply. It gives you the power of a (CMOS?) transistor. Though you can scale it up by multiplying by the number of transistors in a processor (near 5.5B), I'm sure this is way off the mark. The power of a modern Intel processor can vary by at least a couple of orders of magnitude from moment to moment.

As an interesting set of exercises, (1) take the max and min power requirements from the spec, and compute the required C (linear with regards to P in the equation); and (2) get a spec for one switching device using the technology of a modern Intel processor, and multiply it by the # of such devices (>5.5B) to get the "required" power.

Comment: Modern CPUs really go to extremes to save power.  Power-gating means the number of transistors being switched changes from microsecond to microsecond.  (And really from clock to clock in the execution units, depending on workload.)  You could measure the instantaneous switched capacitance, but different parts of the chip run at different voltages.  Leakage power may be non-negligible, I forget.  So I agree, any number you could come up with for `C` would be pretty meaningless.

Comment: @Taylor: Thanks for the answer. Do you think that a derived eq. from the above is not applicable to estimate the power consumption of a process if I know the amount of respective CPU instructions in a given time?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. As Peter said, the processor/cores/uncore power gate part of their circuitry, among other things, when not that active. In addition, p-states are voltage/freq pairs used to reduce power during runtime. If you want to know more, look at this [article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/power-management-states-p-states-c-states-and-package-c-states).